# Nested then() functions returning the promises earlier even before completion of nested then() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 2 functions which should call one after the other Like below.

```
MainFunc().then(DrawChart());
```

MainFunc() function internally have nested functions like I have mentioned below.

I want MainFuc() to return promise or in other way DrawChart() function should call once the createMultiBatchDropdown() is completed.

I checked some links : [Nesting asynchronous jquery promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167396/nesting-asynchronous-jquery-promises)
But I dont want to use any set timeout or delay functions.

I'm new to the concept of this then() and promise() function.Any help will be appreciated.

```
function MainFunc(){
  var r = $.Deferred();
  var xhr = BatchTypeFilterList(data,id).then(function(res){
     //Logic goes here
     var impactXhr = GetImpactData(id).then(function(result){
         var DropXhr = createMultiBatchDropdown('ImpactBatchSearch',result)
     })
  })
 return r.promise(xhr);
}
function BatchTypeFilterList(){
   var deferred = $.Deferred();
   var xhr = $.ajax({
                  //Ajax Call
              success:function(result){
                   deferred.resolve(result);
                 }
              })
    return deferred.promise(xhr);
}
function GetImpactData(){
   var deferred = $.Deferred();
   var xhr = $.ajax({
                  //Ajax Call
              success:function(result){
                   deferred.resolve(result);
                 }
              })
    return deferred.promise(xhr);
}
function createMultiBatchDropdown(){
  var batchDropDownDeferred = $.Deferred();
  //No ajax call normal jquery logic to form dropdown

  batchDropDownDeferred.resolve(data);
  return batchDropDownDeferred.promise(xhr);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [then() callback firing before promise is resolved in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43644230/then-callback-firing-before-promise-is-resolved-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

`GetImpactData` returns a `Promise`, but it's not chained with the outer `xhr`, which means that calling `MainFunc` will result in a `Promise` that resolves *before* `createMultiBatchDropdown` has been called. Instead, `return` the `Promise` created by `createMultiBatchDropdown` so that it's chained with the whole Promise chain properly. You also need to return `impactXhr` to complete the chain. Change to:

```
var xhr = BatchTypeFilterList(data, id).then(function(res) {
  //Logic goes here
  var impactXhr = GetImpactData(id).then(function(result) {
    return createMultiBatchDropdown('ImpactBatchSearch', result);
  })
  return impactXhr;
})
```

Comment: No it's not working by the time GetImpactData() function executed meaning once ajax comes to success the  DrawChart() is calling then createMultiBatchDropdown( ) is calling